# NHibernate 2nd level cache provider for NHibernate 2.1.1.4000

Tags: nhibernate, s#arp-architecture, assembly-resolution, second-level-cache

I am using s#arp which is built against NHibernate 2.1.1.4000, However I would like to use NHibernate.Caches.SysCache as my second level cache. However the Nhibernate contrib caches are built against NHibernate 2.1.2.4000 which obviously gives me a problem.

Can anyone point me to a URL that I can download NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.dll that is built against NHibernate 2.1.1.4000

Or is there another 2nd level cache provider that is easy to implement and is built against NHibernate 2.1.1.4000

Thanks

Comment: why don't you just grab the source code and compile it with NHibernate 2.1.1.4000?

Comment: mmm, I was thinking about this, however I was hoping that someone might have a link to the DLL that I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would update to the 2.1.2 build of NHibernate core and NHCache from nhforge.org, and use an assembly binding redirect to update the s#arp reference.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.1.1.4000" newVersion="2.1.2.4000"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for this, I was hoping for a quick fix where I could just download the correct version of the DLL

Comment: I did this the other way around, I did not update nHibernate rather set my binding redirect from `old=2.1.2.4000` to `new=2.1.1.4000`, seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 1):

S#arp Architecture 1.5.2 supports NHibernate 2.1.2.4000 out of the box now. If you can move to MVC 2, you can upgrade to this version.

Comment: Hi Alec thanks for the update, nice to see you made it to S.O